# Return com 2 Valores C#

Tags: c#, .net, return, value

Eu quero dar `return` de dois valores no c#. Meu código esta assim atualmente, apenas retornando o `imagePath`, mas quero retornoar o `imagePath` e o `normalPath` ao mesmo tempo.

```
string imagePath = "~/Images/QrCode.jpg";
string normalPath = "~/Images/TESTE.jpg";
return imagePath;
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

É possível, se estiver a usar C#7 ou superior, usando [Tuples](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/whats-new/csharp-7#tuples).

```
public (string, string) OseuMetodo()
{    
    string imagePath = "~/Images/QrCode.jpg";
    string normalPath = "~/Images/TESTE.jpg";
    return (imagePath, normalPath);
}
```

Chame o método desta forma:

```
var (imagePath, normalPath) = OseuMetodo();
```

O código acima não só declara as variáveis `imagePath` e `normalPath` como lhes atribuí os respectivos valores retornados.

Answer (score 3):

Existem algumas possíveis soluções pra esse problema, mas em nenhuma você retorna dois valores.

1.Você pode transformar o método em `void` e receber duas variáveis para "retornar" o que precisa:

```
public void CarregarPath (ref string imagePath, ref string normalPath){
    imagePath = "~/Images/QrCode.jpg";
    normalPath = "~/Images/TESTE.jpg";
}
```

2.Pode retornar um *array* com o esses dois caras:

```
public string[] CarregarPath (){
    string[] retorno = new string[2];

    retorno[imagePath] = "~/Images/QrCode.jpg";
    retorno[normalPath] = "~/Images/TESTE.jpg";

    return retorno;
}
```

3.Caso tenha mais atributos pra esse cara, pode criar uma classe e retorná-la:

```
public class PathCompleto {
    string ImagePath { get; set; }
    string NormalPath { get; set; }
}

public PathCompleto  CarregarPath (){
    PathCompleto  retorno = new PathCompleto();

    retorno.ImagePath = "~/Images/QrCode.jpg";
    retorno.NormalPath = "~/Images/TESTE.jpg";

    return retorno;
}
```